How to draw this matrix with stairs and submatrices?
How to draw this matrix?

Is it possible to draw this matrix with help of nicematrix package?
Thanks.

The following solution, which employs a basic array environment, assures that the five columns have equal widths and that the five rows have equal heights.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{relsize}% for \mathlarger macro
\usepackage{calc}   % for \widthof macro
% handy shortcut macro:
\newcommand{\RHSrule}{\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\vphantom{\ddots}}} % "right-hand-side rule"

\begin{document}

\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{2pt} % optional (default: 5pt)
\left[ 
\begin{array}{@{} *{5}{wc{\widthof{$A^{(m,m)}$}}} @{}}
A^{(1,1)} & A^{(1,2)} & \dots & \dots & A^{(1,m)} \vphantom{\ddots} \\
\cline{1-1}
\RHSrule & \ddots & \ddots & & \vdots \\
\cline{2-2}
& \RHSrule & & \ddots & \\
\cline{3-3}
& \mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathbf{0}}} & \RHSrule & \ddots & \vdots \\
\cline{4-4}
& & & \RHSrule & A^{(m,m)} \\
\end{array}
\right]
\]

\end{document}


Addendum:

If you look really closely at the screenshot above -- you may need to click on the image and load the image in a separated viewer -- you may notice that there's a slight flaw in the execution of the staircase: its inside corners between rows 2 and 3, 3 and 4, and 4 and 5 aren't fully connected; instead, there's a slight gap or notch. This is due to a design limitation of the \cline macro, which doesn't (actually, cannot) take into account the width of the one-column-tall vertical rule that's immediately above and to the left of each one-column-wide horizontal rule drawn by \cline.

If these gaps are something that you think is both noticeable and should be avoided, I suggest you load the hhline package and replace the instructions
\cline{2-2} \cline{3-3} \cline{4-4}

with
\hhline{~|-} \hhline{~~|-} \hhline{~~~|-}

respectively.


For comparison, here's a screenshot of the matrix and staircase with the \hhline directives in place.


If the 0 below the diagonal isn't large enough for your taste, I suggest you (a) load the graphicx package and (b) replace \mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathbf{0}}} with \vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{2}{0}}} or maybe even \smash{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{3}{0}}}}.

I concur with Mico that the steps in the staircase should have equal width and height. However, the common width should be measured with the first column, not the last.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\newlength{\rustamlen}

\begin{document}

\[
\settowidth{\rustamlen}{$A^{(1,1)}$}
\left[\,
  \begin{array}{@{} *{4}{w{c}{\rustamlen}} c @{}}
  A^{(1,1)} & A^{(1,2)} & \cdots & \cdots & A^{(1,m)} \vphantom{\vdots} \\
  \cline{1-1}
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \ddots & \ddots & & \vdots \\
  \cline{2-2}
  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & & \ddots & \\
  \cline{3-3}
  && \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \ddots & \vdots \\
  \cline{4-4}
  & \raisebox{2ex}[0pt]{\Huge\bfseries 0}
  && \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & A^{(m,m)} \vphantom{\vdots}
  \end{array}
\,\right]
\]

\end{document}


If you replace the \begin{array} line with
  \begin{array}{@{} *{5}{c} @{}}

and remove the setting of \rustamlen, that aren't needed, you get


+1. :-) I think that our approaches to setting the usable column widths produce quite similar results in the end, as my code also features \setlength\arraycolsep{2pt}, which reduces the total width of each column by 2*3pt=6pt.

Thanks. Could you explain the meaning of this  \begin{array}{@{} *{5}{c} @{}} line? And is it possible to use bmatrix, instead of array?

@RustamMamin - The width of a c-type column is its "natural" width, i.e., the width that's needed to contain the contents of the widest cell in that column. *{5}{c} is short for ccccc, i.e., 5 columns of type c; this allows columns 3 and 4 to be noticeably narrower than columns 1 and 2 are. The @{} particles suppress whitespace padding at the left-hand and right-hand edges of the array environment.

With {bNiceMatrix} of nicematrix.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{3pt}
$\begin{bNiceMatrix}[left-margin,columns-width=auto]
A^{(1,1)} & A^{(1,2)} & \cdots & \cdots & A^{(1,m)} \\
         & \ddots   & \ddots &        & \vdots \\
\Block{3-3}<\Huge>{0} 
         &          &        & \ddots \\
         &          &        & \ddots & \vdots \\
         &          &        & & A^{(m,m)}
\CodeAfter
  \tikz \draw (2-|1) -| (3-|2) -| (4-|3) -| (5-|4) -| (6-|5) ; 
\end{bNiceMatrix}$
\end{center}

\end{document}

The use of the key columns-width=auto ensures that all the columns have the same width.


If you wish the same total height for the rows, it's possible to add a strut with the command \rule at the beginning of the rows.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{3pt}
$\begin{bNiceArray}{>{\rule[-5pt]{0pt}{20pt}}ccccc}%
  [left-margin,columns-width=auto]
A^{(1,1)} & A^{(1,2)} & \cdots & \cdots & A^{(1,m)} \\
         & \ddots   & \ddots &        & \vdots \\
\Block{3-3}<\Huge>{0} 
         &          &        & \ddots \\
         &          &        & \ddots & \vdots \\
         &          &        & & A^{(m,m)}
\CodeAfter
  \tikz \draw (2-|1) -| (3-|2) -| (4-|3) -| (5-|4) -| (6-|5) ; 
\end{bNiceArray}$
\end{center}

\end{document}



Is there a way to make the heights of rows 1 and 5 the same as the heights of rows 2, 3, and 4?

@Mico. Good remark. I have added a second part to my answer.
